# IE 8 autocomplete with jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a modal jQuery dialog with a number of text fields. The text fields are affected by the standard IE 8 autocomplete (which is desired). However, when the host page is scrolled to any position but the top (either before or after the dialog has been opened), the auotocomplete div is offset by the distance of the scroll (e.g. it appears well below the associated textbox). Effectively, the dialog follows the scroll of the host page, but the autocomplete does not follow. This effect is seen even when the host page has been scrolled before opening the dialog.

```
$("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog({autoOpen: false});
$("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog("option", "title", "Additional Interests Detail");
$("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog("option", "height", 600);
$("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog("option", "width", 1000);
$("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog("option", "modal", true);
```

I'm having a hard time finding anything out there that isn't talking about the jQuery autocomplete feature, which I am NOT using here.
Thanks!

Comment: why do you using two closing curly brackets ('}}') in the first line?

Comment: oops, just a typo when I was transferring code. that's not in the original. - fixed

Comment: Try using `class` instead of `ID`'s like `$(".InterestsDetailModalContainer")`

Comment: I appreciate the possible refactor, but this is certainly not the cause of the issue I described.

Comment: Try to make a fiddle, to define your question more understandable...

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the options in a single line of selector like the following:

```
 $("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog({
                          autoOpen: false,
                          title: "Additional Interests Detail",
                          height: 600,
                          width: 1000,
                          modal: true,
    });
```

Try this, It's not a solution, but try this and let know weather solved.

Comment: add your front end and update your question. Still its complicated to understand the question.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. The page that has this code basically just has a div called InterestDetailModalContainer with an iframe InterestDetailFrame. Then a button runs 
    $("#InterestsDetailFrame")[0].src = launchMe;
    $("#InterestsDetailModalContainer").dialog('open');            where launchMe is a URL of a page with text boxes in a form.